# How to escape to use page's names like string "Index"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am wondering is there a good approach to escape of using

```
return RedirectToAction("Index")
```

and to use something like

```
return RedirectToAction(AppPAges.Index.ToString())
```

So the idea is to get rid of possible errors like

```
return RedirectToAction("Indexx")
```

Have we use enumeration or static class for that?

Thank you!

P.S.

I just found this great article http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Kill-magic-strings-with-T4MVC.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a project called [T4MVC](https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) that you can use.

It provides strong typing for your views and actions.

It has a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4MVC/) package as well.

The advantage of using this is you don't have to manage the process. It automatically generates the required classes as you add views/actions or other applicable resources.

Instead of using the string literal "index" you can use as below.

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.Index); //assuming we are in HomeController
```